# Find the lowest line given the same x-axis

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry

There are a bunch of lines in the 2D Plane. Is there an efficient algorithm to find the line that has the lowest y value given the same x? Thank you!

Could we also generate a list of ranges, where for each range, we know which line has the lowest y?

For example, for `y = x + 2` and `y = 2x` for `x` in `[0,100]`, we know that `y = 2x` is lower in the range `[0,2]`, and `y = x+2` is lower in the range `[2,100]`.

Comment: For your first question, what do you mean by "given the same x"?  What is the input to the algorithm?  Please ask only one question per post.  What do you mean by "slower"?  Do you mean "lower"?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/7420193/5376789

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question, if no preprocessing is allowed, there is no better way than computing all intersections with the vertical at $x$. This is an easy $O(n)$ process.

For the second question, refer to the link in the comments. The duality means that to find the relevant intersections of the lines of equations $y=m_kx+p_k$, you need to find the lower hull of the points $(m_k,p_k)$. This is efficiently solved by the  Monotone Chain algorithm in time $O(n\log n)$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms#Algorithms

When you have obtained the intersections that define the envelope, solving for an arbitrary $x$ is done in time $O(\log n)$ by dichotomic search.